# Python Logging is failing

Tags: python, logging

Just started to look up on the logging module and created a dummy program to understand the logger, handler and formatter. Here is the code

```
# logging_example.py

import logging
from datetime import datetime
import os

extension = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%b-%Y_%H_%M_%S_%p")
logfile = os.path.join("logs", f"demo_logging_{extension}.txt")

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

ch = logging.StreamHandler()
fh = logging.FileHandler(logfile)

ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")

ch.setFormatter(formatter)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(ch)
logger.addHandler(fh)

logger.info("Hello World")
```

When i execute the program the logs directory has the files but content is empty and nothing gets printed on the screen to. I am pretty sure I am missing something basic but am not able to catch it though :( .

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: Did the answer work for you as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added log-level to the handlers but not to the logger. Which means, handler would have logged the message had the logger passed it. But since the logger threshold is higher it got dropped.

[See this link](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-flow)

Add log-level to the logger also.
After adding the handlers:

```
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```