# python logging setting debug level

Tags: python

When I run the below piece of code, the logging is working fine. But when I comment #1) and #2) under setup_logger the log is not displayed.

What does #1) and #2) do here?

```
import logging
import sys
def get_logger(name):
    print('get_logger -- ', name)
    log = logging.getLogger("hello.{}".format(name))    
    return log

def setup_logger():
    print('setup_logger')
    root = logging.getLogger("")
    root.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

    handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
        fmt="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
    ))
    root.addHandler(handler)

    logger = logging.getLogger("hello")    #1
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)         #2

LOG = get_logger(__name__)
setup_logger()
print(LOG)

def main():
    LOG.debug('hello')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Have a look at my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65867473/python-logging-is-failing/65867708

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line you marked gets a logger with given name. If there currently is no logger with the name you provided, a new one will be created (Also known as [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Python_implementation)). You can read more about `logging.getLogger` [in the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger) :

> Return a logger with the specified name or, if name is None, return a logger
> which is the root logger of the hierarchy. If
> specified, the name is typically a dot-separated hierarchical name
> like ‘a’, ‘a.b’ or ‘a.b.c.d’. Choice of these names is entirely up to
> the developer who is using logging.
>
> All calls to this function with a given name return the same logger instance.
> This means that logger instances never need to be
> passed between different parts of an application.

The second line you marked sets the loglevel on the logger instance. If you set the loglevel to `DEBUG`, all messages you log will be printed to the console / file. If you set it to `INFO`, all messages except for
debug messages will be logged. And so on. [Quote from the docs again](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel):

> Sets the threshold for this logger to level. Logging messages which
> are less severe than level will be ignored; logging messages which
> have severity level or higher will be emitted by whichever handler or
> handlers service this logger, unless a handler’s level has been set to
> a higher severity level than level.
>
> When a logger is created, the level is set to NOTSET (which causes all
> messages to be processed when the logger is the root logger, or
> delegation to the parent when the logger is a non-root logger). Note
> that the root logger is created with level WARNING.

If you still have questions, I can edit my post to answer them.